# lstlisting produces empty row when used inside a tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, listings

Is there any way I can get rid of the empty new row produced by `lstlisting` inside a `tabular`?

[image]

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=python,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
tabsize=4, 
frame=trbl,
frameround=tttt,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
showstringspaces=false,
numbers=left,
breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l | p{0.8\textwidth}}
test &
\begin{lstlisting}
somecode
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}

rest of text


\end{document}
```

I'm using TexShop with xelatex.

Follow-up question: It also seems to break when I'm using `longtable`: The tables don't continue into other pages, instead it creates huge gaps and I'm suspecting it has to do with `lstlisting`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the option

```
belowskip=-\baselineskip
```

So

```
\begin{tabular}{l | p{0.8\textwidth}}
test &
\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-\baselineskip]
somecode
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
```

There is also `aboveskip`

Comment: I get missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: The option must be added when calling the environment. It's an option for `\lstset`, but I don't think it's good to put it in the general options. I put it in the wrong place, sorry.

Comment: It seems to work for tables, but seems to break if I have text immediately after when it's not inside a table: http://i.imgur.com/C98iu.png

Comment: @pg-robban That's why it's better to set `belowskip` to zero only when really needed: don't put in `\lstset`, but only as optional argument in tables.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw your update. It works now. Thanks :)